# Is this an accepted/given form of the definition of derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{x+h}f(x)dx}{h}=f'(x)$$

Is this an accepted/given/understood form of the definition of derivative?  Or does one need to work this into the traditional difference quotient format (below) before one can just infer/state that this limit is the same as the derivative of f(x)?

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: The integral of $f$ from $x$ to $x+h$ isn't the same as $f(x+h) - f(x)$.

Comment: I am not claiming the integral is equal to f(x+h)-f(x).  I am claiming the 2 limits are equivalent.  Hence, the first limit is an "alternate" form of the definition of derivative.  I just want to know if that's accepted, or if it needs to be proven/derived.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 1$. Then under your first definition $f'(x) = 1$, while under the second definition $f'(x) = 0$. So the two don't match up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Dylon notes, your formula is not the same as the definition of the derivative. In fact, if $f$ is integrable with antiderivative $F$,

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\int_x^{x+h} f(x)\, dx}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = F'(x) = f(x).$$

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed to see in order to explicitly connect that first limit to the difference quotient format.

Answer (score 3):

Your integrand is incorrect. You would need:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{x+h}f'(x)dx}{h}=f'(x)$$

Which is not very useful for finding a derivative since you need to already know the derivative in order to find it.